# @dnd-kit not allowing to prevent dragging items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dnd-kit

I'm using this `npm` package: `@dnd-kit` https://github.com/clauderic/dnd-kit to be able to drag drop elements up and down in a vertical list. Dragging elements works perfect for me. My problem is that based on some condition I need to block the dragging of the elements at all.

To reproduce the issue you can follow these steps:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/clauderic/dnd-kit
$ cd dnd-kit
$ git checkout master # currently: d5c4732d7262c773db338850e9b2bb386c938ddf
$ yarn
$ yarn start:storybook
```

On file: `/stories/2 - Presets/Sortable/1-Vertical.story.tsx`, just add the highlighted text on the screenshot below...

[image]

Here is the added text so you can copy paste:

```
export const LockedBothAxis = () => (
  <Sortable
    {...props}
    modifiers={[restrictToHorizontalAxis, restrictToVerticalAxis, restrictToWindowEdges]}
  />
);
```

where you can see my intention is to block the dragging on both axis: `horizontal` and `vertical`. Whenever the block condition is `true` I tried by using those 2 modifiers above:  `{ restrictToHorizontalAxis, restrictToVerticalAxis }` (which doesn't totally work).

Now go to: http://localhost:6006/?path=/story/presets-sortable-vertical--locked-both-axis and try to drag the items.

If you try a short distance dragging then you will notice the dragging doesn't work (so far so good).

**My problem is:** If you try a long distance dragging (all the way up or down) then you will notice that you can actually drag the items.

**What I need:** When the user long presses an item, the item gets highlighted but when he tries a short or a long distance dragging, the item doesn't get dragged.

Below you have a demostration of my issue, where I try first a short distance dragging up and down and the item doesn't get dragged (so far so good). But later I try a long distance dragging down and the item gets dragged (my issue)...

[image]

Any idea on how to block the dragging at all even if the user does a long distance dragging?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add *disabled: true* to useSortable or useDraggable

```
const [disableDnD, setDisableDnD] = useState(true);


const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, transition, isDragging } = useSortable({ id, disabled: disableDnD });
```

Here are props:
https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/draggable/usedraggable#arguments